# Exit to shell during boot, Raspbian

Tags: raspbian

I think I made some error in the startup script on my Raspbian. I can still see the boot display, is there a way to exit to shell so I can fix with nano the scripts I added?

Comment: What is the "boot display"?

Comment: if you are in a shell you can still use nano, I don't see the issue here, please collaborate.

Comment: Boot display, the texts after the raspberry image below. Problem is I am not sure how to go to the shell during boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a keyboard attached press ctrl+alt+f1 to get a login shell.

Press ctrl+alt+f7 to return.